# Saving form data using localstorage and dynamically reading data to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently creating a signup form for a client and one of the requirements is for the form to be able to transmit and store data offline. I have already tried to work with a database, but I am still in beginning stages learning php so I decided t quit while I am behind.

I found another method of storign data locally suing localstorage with JS, but I am unable to display the stored data in a dynamic table.

Any help on this matter would be greatky appreciated, here is the code I have so far

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CIVIC Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="civic.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <style>
   p.finePrint {
    color:#818185;
    font-size:70%;
   }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   (function()
   {
    var Applicant = {
     fname: "",
     lname: "",
     age: 0,
     phonenum: "",
     email: ""
    };
    
    var storageLogic = {
     saveItem: function (){
      var lscount = localStorage.length;
      var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
      Applicant.fname = inputs[0].value;
      Applicant.lname = inputs[1].value;
      Applicant.age = inputs[2].value;
      Applicant.phonenum = inputs[3].value;
      Applicant.email = inputs[4].value;
      
      localStorage.setItem("Applicant_" + lscount, JSON.stringify(Applicant));
      location.reload();
      
     },
     
     loaddata: function() {
      var datacount = localStorage.length;
      if (datacount > 0)
      {
       var render = "<table border='1'>";
       render += "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th>" + 
       "<th>Phone Number</th><th>Email</th>";
       for (i=0; i < datacount; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        var applicant = localStorage.getItem(key);
        var data = JSON.parse(applicant);
        
        render += "<tr><td>" + data.fname + "</td><td>" + data.lname + "</td>";
        render += "<td>" + data.age + "</td>";
        render += "<td>" + data.phonenum + "</td>";
        render += "<td>" + data.email + "</td>";
       }
       render += "</table>";
       var newTable = document.getElementById("dvContainer");
       newTable.innerHTML = render;
      }
     }
    };
  var btnsubmit = document.getElementById('btnsubmit');
  btnsubmit.addEventListener('click', storageLogic.saveItem(), false);
  window.onload = function() {
   storageLogic.loaddata();
  };
   })();
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
   <h2 style="color:#005E28"><img src="civic.jpg" height="50" width="50"></img>CIVIC Registration Form</h2>
   <form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-inline">
   <label for="age">Age: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age"></label>
   <label for="phone">Phone Number: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonenum" placeholder="Phone Number"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div>
  <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> -->
   <input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
   <p class="finePrint">*By submitting this form you agree to receiving emails regarding 
   upcoming events and other information from CIVIC Ontario. 
   If you have any questions or concerns, please email civicontario@gmail.com*</p>
  </div>
   </form>
 </div>
 <div id="dvContainer" class="conatiner">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why dont you set up a jsfiddle or plunk.  Not cool to just dump all your work here and expect someone to make your life easier when you dont even bother to make theirs easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are primarily two errors you need to fix:

- Move the `getElementById()` and `addEventListener()` for id `btnsubmit` to your `onload` handler. The way it is now, it tries to find the element before it is actually in the DOM.
- You are accidentally invoking the handler that is the second parameter of `addEventListener()`. In other words, get rid of the `()` after the second parameter.

Here is a version of your code with those changes that seems to minimally work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CIVIC Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="civic.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <style>
    p.finePrint {
        color:#818185;
        font-size:70%;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function()
    {
        var Applicant = {
            fname: "",
            lname: "",
            age: 0,
            phonenum: "",
            email: ""
        };

        var storageLogic = {
            saveItem: function (){
                var lscount = localStorage.length;
                var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
                Applicant.fname = inputs[0].value;
                Applicant.lname = inputs[1].value;
                Applicant.age = inputs[2].value;
                Applicant.phonenum = inputs[3].value;
                Applicant.email = inputs[4].value;

                localStorage.setItem("Applicant_" + lscount, JSON.stringify(Applicant));
                location.reload();

            },

            loaddata: function() {
                var datacount = localStorage.length;
                if (datacount > 0)
                {
                    var render = "<table border='1'>";
                    render += "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th>" + 
                    "<th>Phone Number</th><th>Email</th>";
                    for (i=0; i < datacount; i++) {
                        var key = localStorage.key(i);
                        var applicant = localStorage.getItem(key);
                        var data = JSON.parse(applicant);

                        render += "<tr><td>" + data.fname + "</td><td>" + data.lname + "</td>";
                        render += "<td>" + data.age + "</td>";
                        render += "<td>" + data.phonenum + "</td>";
                        render += "<td>" + data.email + "</td>";
                    }
                    render += "</table>";
                    var newTable = document.getElementById("dvContainer");
                    newTable.innerHTML = render;
                }
            }
        };
        window.onload = function() {
            storageLogic.loaddata();
      var btnsubmit = document.getElementById('btnsubmit');
      btnsubmit.addEventListener('click', storageLogic.saveItem, false);
        };
    })();
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2 style="color:#005E28"><img src="civic.jpg" height="50" width="50"></img>CIVIC Registration Form</h2>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <label for="age">Age: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age"></label>
            <label for="phone">Phone Number: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonenum" placeholder="Phone Number"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div>
        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> -->
            <input id="btnsubmit" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
            <p class="finePrint">*By submitting this form you agree to receiving emails regarding 
            upcoming events and other information from CIVIC Ontario. 
            If you have any questions or concerns, please email civicontario@gmail.com*</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="dvContainer" class="conatiner">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```